# Cakephp custom validation for input

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I have model (List) which have a list of values: 5 10 20 30 40 50

I have a input value where i must to insert a minimal value which is the previous value insert.
if i insert 7 the next minimal value should be 10. if i insert 11 the next minimal value is 20.

My question is how can validate this input?
in model i have:

```
'valor_licitacao' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('comparison', '>=', 20000),
            'message' => 'The value must be greater then 20000'
        )
    )
```

how can i define a rule that says: "the values should be greater than `List->find('first', 'conditions' => array('List.valor > '.$mylastvalue)));`

Thanks in advance, please feel free to ask any question about this.

Comment: Have you tried searching on google on [how to define validation rules in cake](https://www.google.cl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JBaSU-PCDIuF8QeO3IHYDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=custom+validation+rule+cakephp)? Read cake docs for [custom validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules)? anything?

Comment: yes.I'm new in cakephp and I'm looking for any suggestion to help me with this problem. I've already read the documentation, but i can't understand how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a custom validation method. This method can look as the input field and if it is greater than the lower band, you can set it to the value you want.

Comment: thanks david, but how can i load a value from another model? a dynamic value? in that example you have a 'rule'    => array('limitDuplicates', 25). how can i say in cakephp that 25 is a value from another model. It is possible to load a model inside a class model? does it make sense?

Comment: You are in the model, so you can get to anywhere. `$this->data` will be the models data. `$this->Model->field` would be a related model.